# Changing Jquery Mobile FlipSwitch selected value Programmatically

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-flipswitch

I am trying to change flip switch value programmatically but its not working
here is the HTML

```
<label for="flip-1">Flip switch:</label>
<select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider">
    <option value="NG">NG</option>
    <option value="OK">OK</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="name" />
<input type="number" id="age" />
```

Here is the Script

```
$("#flip-1").on('slidestart', function (event) {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    if (name == "" || age == "") {

        $("#flip-1").val("NG").flipswitch("refresh");
    } else[
    // slide it to OK
    ]
});
```

What i need is that `NG` to be selected all the time but only if there is some text in both inputs

Here is the Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r9X5U/6/

Comment: `What i need is that NG to be selected all the time but only if there is some text in both inputs` ??

Comment: @Aravin :When ever user click on switch it checks the name and age input fields if there is some value in both fields then switch flips to OK otherwise stay on NG

Comment: check this one http://jsfiddle.net/7fCYA/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like the following it will work. Set change event for flip switch.

HTML is like

```
<select  name="flip-3" id="snd-switch" data-role="flipswitch" data-mini="true">
    <option value="NG">NG</option>
    <option value="OK">OK</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="name" />
<input type="text" id="age" />
```

Javascript is like:

```
$("#snd-switch").on('change', function (event) {
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
if(name == "" || age == ""){
   // alert("hi");
    $("#snd-switch").val("NG").flipswitch("refresh");
}else{
   $("#snd-switch").val("OK").flipswitch("refresh");
}
});
```

Here is the **<kbd>[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7fCYA/3/)</kbd>**

Answer (score 1):

I would reverse the logic, checking the `input` fields and enabling the flipswitch when needed.
HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <label for="flip-1">Flip switch:</label>
    <select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="flipswitch">
        <option value="NG">NG</option>
        <option value="OK">OK</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="name" />
    <input type="number" id="age" />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#page").bind("pageshow", function()
{
    $("#flip-1").flipswitch("disable");

    $("#name,#age").on("keyup", function(event, ui)
    {
        if ($("#name").val().length !== 0 && $("#age").val().length !== 0)
            $("#flip-1").flipswitch("enable");
        else
            $("#flip-1").flipswitch("disable");
    });    
});
```